# How to add newline in shell_exec php?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, cmd

I want to execute a node.js file via php.
The thing that I want to achieve in PHP is this

```
C:proj> node main.js text="This is some text.
>> some more text in next line"
```

My php script

```
shell_exec('node C:\proj\main.js text="This is some text. \n some more text in next line"');
```

But in my main.js file, I'm only getting

```
text = this is some text.
```

rest of the string is getting removed.
Could anyone help please?

Things I've tried

1. \n
2. `n
3. >>
4. PHP_EOL
5. ^
6. ^\n

but no luck!

I hope my question is clear. Please feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
shell_exec("node C:\proj\main.js text=\"This is some text.\n>> some more text in next line\"");
```

will equivalent of your console command

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy but this is not working and I've already tried this before.